# input in table > td, But yet extra bottom spacing between rows! Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

Im using [meyer css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css). But I have problem with input in a table. There in extra space between rows:

```
<table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="black"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><input type="text" /></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="black"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and css:

```
   .table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
    }
   .table tr {
margin-bottom:0;
overflow:hidden;
height:25px;
width: 100%;
padding:0;
   }
  .table input {
width:25px;
height:25px;
border:1px solid #000;
text-align:center;
   }
   .black {
background:#000;
    }
```

Why there is extra bottom spacing in internet explorer (I hate ie :(()? 
Thanks alot

Comment: Where? looks cool to me: http://jsfiddle.net/Buc2D/

Comment: looks horrible in ie : http://jsfiddle.net/uRv5a/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the border on the td and not on the input.
Give the cells you want black a black class and the others with input the tdinput class.  That way, you still get the cells with numbers without borders :)

```
<td>1</td>
<td class='tdinput'><input type="text"/></td>
<td class='tdinput black'><input type="text" /></td>


td.tdinput
{
    border:1px solid #000;
}
td.tdinput.black input
{
     background:#000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, This is very cool solution and my problem is solve by this. (but extra 100 class)

Comment: Yes, extra class, but you might avoid that with some inovative javascript instead (or jQuery selector/manipulation)

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the border off of the .inputs and actually put it on the td's.

Try this

```
.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
.table tr {
    margin-bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:25px;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
}
.table tr td {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.table input {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
}
.black {
    background:#000;
}
```

Comment: I have tried td borders but it looks like this in ie
http://jsfiddle.net/uRv5a/42/

Answer (score 1):

It's because inputs are inline elements. add `display:block;` to your input elements and it should take off the gap.

```
.table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
.table tr {
    margin-bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:25px;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
}
.table tr td {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.table input {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
.black {
    background:#000;
}
```

Basically adding `display:block;` to Catfish's solution as he also makes a valid point about styling both td and input. :)

Comment: with display:block there is gap yet :(

Answer (score 0):

The bottom margin is being caused by the way IE is handling your input.

Adding:     `margin:-1px;` such that:

```
  .table input {
width:25px;
height:25px;
border:1px solid #000;
text-align:center;
margin:-1px;
   }
```

Seems to fix it quite well.

Comment: Put it in your seperate IE stylesheet :-)

Comment: edl's answer is a better answer infact.

Comment: If it solves your problem in IE (which version(s) ?) but creates ont in Fx, Saf, Chr and Op then use a conditional comment to target only IE6 or IE7 and lower or IE8 and lower. Beware that if it's OK in IE8 you mustn't target it (and to be future-proof, trust IE9 developers that it won't need this negative margin either /me crossing fingers)

Comment: This cannot solve in ie7 : http://jsfiddle.net/uRv5a/56/
I have tried ANYTHING but no result